# Pluralization issue: "1 tag wiki edits"

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, badge-progress, plurals

There's a pluralization issue in the About page of tags, under "Your Badge Progress", when only 1 tag wiki has been edited:

[image]

It should be 1 tag wiki **edit**.